# Splitting multiple lists in columns in multiple rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for the best way to transform this matrix

[image]

```
pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]], ['a', ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f', 'g']]])
```

Into this

[image]

```
pd.DataFrame(data=[[ 1, 2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5, 7], ['a', 'b', 'd', 'f'], ['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']])
```

Columns 1, 2, 3 can have longer lists but are per definition of equal length.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `pd.DataFrame.explode` with a list of columns:

```
df.explode([1,2,3])
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  4  6
0  1  3  5  7
1  a  b  d  f
1  a  c  e  g
```

Or with `ignore_index=True`:

```
df.explode([1,2,3], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  4  6
1  1  3  5  7
2  a  b  d  f
3  a  c  e  g
```